# Images in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

How come I can't add images using this:

```
from tkinter import * 
root = Tk()

def logo():
    photo = PhotoImage(file="Logo.png")
    Label(root, image=photo).grid()

logo()

root.mainloop()
```

But I can add images using this:

```
from tkinter import * 
root = Tk()

photo = PhotoImage(file="Logo.png")
Label(window, image=photo).grid()

logo()

root.mainloop()
```

Any help?

Comment: Your variable `photo` is garbage collected the moment you exit the function `logo`; you need to keep a reference to it in the global space, or as an attribute of a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep a reference to the image to prevent it being garbage collected. Try this:

```
def logo():
    photo = PhotoImage(file="Logo.png")
    lbl = Label(root, image=photo)
    lbl.image = photo # keep a reference
    lbl.grid()
```

You don't have to do that in your other block because you are using global variables, which are never garbage collected.

See the note on the bottom of [this page](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm).